# Putting pin drops for some areas in map in android

Tags: android, dictionary

I have some addresses and their lattitude and longitude in Sqlite DataBase.Now I want to point all the addresses with pin drop.Please get me the idea for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=latitude,longitude&zoom=14&size=800x400&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7Clatitude,longitude&sensor=false.The marker is used for pointing the exact position.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dLatitude,dLongitude)).title("your title");
```